# How do I register a .bit domain name with Namecoin?

Tags: namecoin, tor, dns

I have several namecoins and would like to register a name.  That name could either be for TOR, DNS, or any other purpose.

What are the steps needed to spend these coins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm of registering `.bit` domain is described, for example, on [dot-bit wiki](http://dot-bit.org/HowToRegisterAndConfigureBitDomains).

In short:

1. Create new domain name with `name_new` command: `./namecoind name_new d/<name>`
2. Wait 12 or more blocks
3. Actually register the domain with `name_firstupdate`, where `<rand>` is the second (shorter) hexadecimal string returned by `name_new`, and `<json-value>` is the domain configuration (similar to DNS record):

`./namecoind name_firstupdate d/<name> <rand> '<json-value>'`

The basic `json-string`, mapping the domain to the some IP looks like that:

```
'{"ip":"1.2.3.4", "tor":"123456.onion"}'
```

[More on domain configuration](http://dot-bit.org/Namespace%3aDomain_names_v2.0#Value_field)

Comment: I see... I didn't think this was possible when I typed `C:\namecoind_v350_win32>namecoind.exe /?`  on Windows. I'll give it a shot now.